# Why does a molecule with a Thiol group form Hydrogen bonds?

Tags: polarity

I'm doing the GRE Biology practice test, and [question #1](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_biology.pdf#page=9) asks:

[image]

The [answer is E](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_biology.pdf#page=61). I understand why II and IV are polar, but why is $\ce{R-S-H}$ polar? R is a side chain to the sulfur, sulfur's valence shell is full, and sulfur is highly electronegative. But without knowing what $\ce{R}$ is, how do we know the molecule's total polarity?

Comment: The question didn't ask about a molecule's "total polarity," it asked which would form Hydrogen bonds. The [hydrogen on a thiol group](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1742907)  (R-S-H) can form hydrogen bonds with other groups like alcohols and amines. Thiols are sparingly water soluble so III is a bit strange but not impossible. Thiols only form weak hydrogen bonds between themselves.

Comment: @MaxW That answers it, thanks! If you'd like an accepted answer, please convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept. Either way, thank you.

Comment: @freeradical Could you please update the question title - in your own words - to reflect the actual question being asked?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Sorry, just saw this. I've updated the title, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's all four.  See [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0036024416100150) for I.  The article describes a hydrogen bonding interaction between methane and water.  It's weaker than the "usual" hydrogen bonds but still contributes to forming methane-water clathrates.

The larger lesson here is that hydrogen bonding is not just the electrostatic interaction often described in textbooks.  It has a molecular orbital component that works even with primary bonds of low polarity.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks! I'll report this to the GRE folks. I also recently read that the electronegativities of Hydrogen and Carbon are not equal (2.2 and 2.55 respectively), so it makes sense that even Methane is slightly polar and thus can make hydrogen bonds.